# In Eclipse Helios it is impossible to rollback plugin installation

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have eclipse Helios for Java EE and I downloaded all the pluggins related to Modeling Framework. After this all the Java EE aspects are lost! Anyway it is not possible to uninstall the plugins or revert to previous installation.
If I select a plugin and press uninstall I get:

> An error occurred while uninstalling
>   session context
>   was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall,
>   operand=[R]org.eclipse.acceleo.common.source
>   3.0.1.v201009150438 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.RemoveSourceBundleAction).
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils

If I select yesterday's installation and press revert I get:

> An error occurred while uninstalling
>   session context
>   was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall,
>   operand=[R]com.google.collect
>   0.8.0.v201008251220 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils

Why can't I unistall plugins? Is this some issue in Helios??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you followed :

`Help` => `About Eclipse` => `Installation Detail` => `Installed Software Tab` => and then selected a product to remove - from the exception that was *Acceleo* => `Uninstall...`.

And that this yielded the error log you quote.

So I'd consider a 'manual' uninstall.

I've downloaded the acceleo v3 update site and looked into both the plugins and feature folders and all artifacts are named org.eclipse.acceleo.stuff.  This is confirmed by looking into the content.xml (content.jar)

So, I'd backup my eclipse folder, remove all acceleo plugins and features, have a look in my workspace .metadata folder for corresponding memos (the acceleo name again as a filter) and restart with eclipse -clean.

That should start up again.  Otherwse, goto restore !

As for the google collection bundle.  It looks like there was another intervening installation (best interpretation I could come up with, I'm afraid ;-) because I can't see the google collections jar in the acceleo update site.

**Update**
In light of the investigation carried out (see comments below), I'd advise a fresh installation starting with the newer stable 3.6sr1 (Java EE variant) and progressively re-installing the existing plugins (as listed in `Help` => `About Eclipse` => `Installation Detail` => `Installed Software`) one by one from their respective update sites (export from preferences from old installation, reimport in new).  The make new installation point on "old" workspace. Then look at the log view (or log in .metadata) to find out whether all plugins re-installed correctly).

Comment: @Alain:I manually deleted all jars with the date, I installed the Modeling Framework.I am not sure what I should look into .metadata folder of workspace.I started with eclipse -clean. Then I did: `Help->About->Installation Details` and selected a configuration having a date prior the messup and named J2EE configuration.I pressed revert and got no errors.I restarted Eclipse.J2EE aspect is not working despite the fact that under installation tab it is displayed as current installation.Can this be fixed?BTW you are right.I installed euml2 right after installing the GMF

Comment: 1. In .metadata, all plugins needing to keep some user data are allowed to open a folder (with their nale) and place their stuff there.  This is why I suggested to have a look at that folder to complete the clean up.  2.  Can you elaborate on 'J2EE aspect is not working'.  3. Sorry somehow I missed your comment.

Comment: In particular, I don't understand if you are really using AspectJ Development Tools or if 'J2E aspect is not working' means J2E perspective shows errors of some kind.

Comment: @Alain:When I say J2EE aspect is not working I mean e.g. there is no option anymore to create a `Dynamic Web Project` or a new JSP or servlet etc. Also if I right-click on a project and press properties there is no `Build Path` option to set libraries on classpath.It is some weird option `Builder` instead.My last comment was on your note "there was another intervening installation".I installed euml2 right after installing GFM.In .metadata, where am I supposed to look to clean up?

Comment: @user384706   Wow, this is weird !!!  Look at this [screen shot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9999182/Screenshot-Eclipse%20Installation%20Details%20.png) to see if you have the highlighted element in your eclipse products list.

Comment: For metatdata, remove folders having acceleo in the name under this workspace hidden subfolder, if any.

Comment: @Alain:Yes the "Java EE IDE Feature" seems available in the installation tab, but it is not working.In perspectives there is `<JavaEE>` as JEE perspective which actually is wrong since it should have the beans icon and not the `< >` brackets.In metadata there is no folder named acceleo (under plugins).Additionally I went in the artifacts.xml and deleted all tags refering to acceleo (not even sure what artifacts.xml is for).No success.It seems my installation is ruined.Is JavaEE IDE and Java Modeling Framework in eclipse contradicting projects?I.e. one installation cancels the other?

Comment: @Alain:I had euml2 with all its dependencies in Galileo and it was fine!Has Helios any issues in plugins?

Comment: @user384706.  There's no issue that I know of... To be honest with you, it looks like you have now a corrupted installation.  In your position, I think the safest option is to reinstall again.  Is this something You have good reasons to avoid ?

Comment: @Alain:I think I will do that.Do you think it makes any sence to report this to eclipse as a bug?I do not think I did something to cause this

Comment: I think the pb is on acceleo's side.  Googling around I could see a lot of installation and upgrde problems with their bundles.  I don't know whether what they're trying to achieve is hard or not, but you're not the first one to fall victim of trying their product. Besides, they've made their product an eclipse project nt very long ago.  The Eclipse Bugzilla db is well  compartimented so that there is probably an acceleo sub category (not on my 'eclipse' PC at the moment and I can't remember my eclipse bugzilla pwd). See tomorrow.

Comment: @Alain:Add an update in your answer recomending re-installation (leave the post as is and add it bellow) and I will accept it.

Comment: Done.  Please feel free to let me know about further issues you might notice in the log.  Clean (rename) the log in .metadata first.

Comment: I just had a look in eclipse's bugzilla and there are 128 bugs for acceleo.  I scanned rapidly and found none related to removal of the product itself.  If you wish to enter a bug, providing you've registered, please make sure this is 100% reproducible and describe the sequence of actions leading to the condition.